# Running into errors when trying to render and save multiple SSRS reports

Tags: c#, reporting-services, async-await

I need to generate a large number of reports from SSRS and store them in the database. Doing them one at a time is too slow, so I am trying to take advantage of `async` and `await`. Here's the line of where I am trying to do the work. `xxx` contains a collection of reports names, and the parameters that go with those reports.

```
Task.WaitAll(xxx.Select(x => CreateSaveReportTask(x.parameterValue, x.rType, x.batchReportParameter, conn, 
                                                  ssrsUser, ssrsPassword, ssrsDomain, ssrsServerUrl, ssrsVirtualPath)).ToArray());
```

Here's the method that returns the task

```
private async Task CreateSaveReportTask(int parameterValue, HabReportTypeLkup rType, BatchReportConfig batchReportParameter, SqlConnection conn, 
    string user, string password, string domain, string reportServerUrl, string reportServerVirtualPath)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Log.Info("Saving " + parameterValue + " report of type " + rType.Value);
            var parameters = new[] { new ParameterValue { Name = batchReportParameter.ParameterName, Value = parameterValue.ToString() } };

            var rs = new ReportExecutionService();
            rs.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password, domain);
            rs.Url = String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", reportServerUrl, reportServerVirtualPath, "ReportExecution2005.asmx");

            // Render arguments
            byte[] rpt = null;
            string reportPath = rType.ReportPath;
            string format = rType.Format;
            string historyID = null;
            string devInfo = null;

            string encoding, mimeType, extension;
            Warning[] warnings = null;
            string[] streamIDs = null;

            var execInfo = new ExecutionInfo();
            var execHeader = new ExecutionHeader();

            try
            {
                rs.ExecutionHeaderValue = execHeader;
                rs.LoadReport(reportPath, historyID);
                rs.SetExecutionParameters(parameters, "en-us");

                rpt = rs.Render(format, devInfo, out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);
                Log.Info("SUCCESS RETRIEVING " + rpt.Count() + " bytes for " + parameterValue + " report of type " + rType.Id + "(" + rType.Value + ")");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error("ERROR RETRIEVING " + parameterValue + " report of type " + rType.Id + "(" + rType.Value + ")");
                Log.Error(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
            try
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO habAdmin.HAB_ReportDocument (ReportId, DateLastModified, ReportDocument, ReportTypeId) VALUES (@reportId, @dateLastModified, @report, @reportType)";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new IDbDataParameter[]
                    {
                        new SqlParameter("reportId", parameterValue),
                        new SqlParameter("dateLastModified", DateTime.Now),
                        new SqlParameter("report", rpt),
                        new SqlParameter("reportType", rType.Id)
                    });
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    Log.Info("SUCCESS SAVING " + parameterValue + " report of type " + rType.Id + "(" + rType.Value + ")");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error("ERROR SAVING " + parameterValue + " report of type " + rType.Id + "(" + rType.Value + ")");
                Log.Error(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
        });
}
```

It starts outs working, but pretty quickly, it starts throwing exceptions, like these:

```
//The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
//The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server.
//The request was aborted: The request was canceled.
```

If I decide to let it run for a while, and retry when there are errors, it would eventually go back to getting back the reports for a little but, and then start throwing the exceptions again.

I am guessing that the server is imposing some kind of a limit on me, but I have no way of checking the setting there. Is there a way slow down the number of requests I am making maybe?

Comment: I can't see any error messages.

Comment: They are inside the first catch, i'll edit my post to clarify